# Assert Scipy Univariate Spline Strictly Increasing

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I'm working with univariate splines from scipy. A simple example of one is as follows:

```
import scipy    

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
f = scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y)
```

Is there any way I could make the resulting spline strictly increasing or strictly decreasing? I've noticed that, even if I feed it strictly increasing or decreasing data points, the result won't necessarily have this property.

Answer (score 0):

Look for monotone interpolants, pchip and/or akima. These are at least locally monotone.